# Render block tag as DIV in jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I know block tags intended use is to replace parent's content and/or provide a placeholder so that childs can fill in content. But in order to avoid manual repetition and maybe inconsistencies I wonder if there id any way to make {%block something%} get rendered as  (or any other HTML element).

Example:

```
{% block content %}
Hello world
{% endblock content %}
```

Renders as:

```
...
<div id="content"> 
Hello world 
</div>
...
```

I'm using jinja2 with flask

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to move the block inside the tag.

```
<div id="content">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

If there are times when you want to use a different tag, you can always wrap the whole thing in another block.

```
{% block contenttag %}
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. As I can have a  different parent template depending on some request parameters I would have to repeat the DIV on each of them

Comment: Do they inherit from a common base? Could it be defined in there?

Comment: Parent templates are at the top of the hierarchy. Imagine a "layout_full.html" and a "layout_ajax.html" as possible parents.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally been able to do this by implementing my own Jinja2 loader, and injecting the elements in the contents loaded from disk.